# program doesn't output any choice bigger than 9

Tags: c++, vector, output

I am quite new to C++ and been trying to make my own traveling program. For some reason, after pushing back the information into vectors, upon request of output anything bigger than 9 the program refuses to output it. For example, there are 10 cities in the program, and i chose to visit cities 1 2 3 10. The program outputs only cities 1, 2, 3. Would really appreciate help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct Cities
{
string name;
double x;
double y;
};

void add_city(string add, Cities temp, vector<Cities>&file_info)
{
cin>>add;

if (add!="Y" && add!="N")
{
    cout<<"Incorrect input, please enter Y or N: "<<endl;
    cin>>add;
}
if(add=="Y")
{
    while (add=="Y")
    {
        cout<<"enter name of destination, x and y coordinates "<<endl;
        cin>>temp.name>>temp.x>>temp.y;                     
        file_info.push_back(temp);
        cout<<"If you would like to add another city, please enter Y, if not, please enter N: "<<endl;
        cin>>add;
    }

}

if(add=="N")
{
    for (int i=0; i<file_info.size();i++)
        cout<<i+1<<'\t'<<file_info[i].name<<endl;
}
}

void Distances_between_cities(vector<double>distances2, double minimum_distance, double maximum_distance, double sum_of_distances)
{
minimum_distance=0;
maximum_distance=0;
sum_of_distances=0;
distances2.erase(std::remove(distances2.begin(), distances2.end(), 0), distances2.end());
minimum_distance=*min_element(distances2.begin(), distances2.end()); //displays 0 as 0 is the dist between same cities so need to change that
cout<<endl<<"Minimum distance you will travel: "<<minimum_distance<<endl;
maximum_distance=*max_element(distances2.begin(), distances2.end()); //sorts through the vector, finds the biggest element in the vector
cout<<"Maximum distance you will travel: "<<maximum_distance<<endl; //displays the biggest element of the vector
for (int n: distances2)
    sum_of_distances +=n;
cout<<"Total distance: "<<sum_of_distances/2<<endl;
}

void password_protection(string password, string password_input)
{
 cin >> password_input;
 while (password_input!=password)
 {
    cout << "Incorrect password, please re-enter password: "<<endl;
    cin>>password_input;
}
if (password_input==password)
    cout<<"Authorised."<<endl;
}

void clear_vectors(vector<Cities>&file_info, vector<Cities>&choices)
{
file_info.swap(std::vector<Cities>());
choices.swap(std::vector<Cities>());

}

void Table(vector<Cities>&choices, double dist, vector<double>&distances2 )
{
for (int i=0; i<choices.size(); i++)
cout<<'\t'<<choices[i].name<<'\t';
                cout<<endl;
for (int a=0; a<choices.size(); a++)
                {
                cout<<choices[a].name<<'\t';
                    for (int b=0; b<choices.size(); b++)
                    {
                        double xi=choices[a].x;
                        double xa=choices[b].x;
                        double yi=choices[a].y;
                        double ya=choices[b].y;
                        dist=sqrt((xi-xa)*(xi-xa)+(yi-ya)*(yi-ya));
                        distances2.push_back(dist);
                        cout<<dist<<'\t'<<'\t';
                    }
                    cout<<endl;
                }
}

void read_from_file(string name_of_file, Cities temp,  vector<Cities>file_info)
{
cout<<"Please enter the name of the file you want to read information from: "<<endl;
        cin>>name_of_file;
         ifstream file;
         file.open(name_of_file);
         if (file.is_open())
        {
            while(file>>temp.name>>temp.x>>temp.y)
            {
                file_info.push_back(temp);
            }

            for (int i=0; i<file_info.size(); i++)
                 cout<<i+1<<'\t'<<file_info[i].name<<endl;

        }
        else 
            cout<<"Error.File not open"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
Cities temp;
ifstream file;
string name_of_file;
vector<Cities> file_info;
vector<Cities>choices;
vector<double> distances;
vector<int>x_coordinate;
vector<int>y_coordinate;
vector<double>distances2;
int sum_of_distances=0;
double minimum_distance;
double maximum_distance;
double b;
double dist;
int user_input;
string password = "anastasia";
string password_input;
string name;
string add;
string Y;
string N;
string add_name;
string input_to_start_program;
string plan;
string Option;
while (1)
{

    cout<<"::::MENU::::"<<'\n'
        <<"::1.Run Program::"<<'\n'
         <<"::2.Display File Contents::"<<'\n'
        <<"::3.Instructions::"<<'\n'
        <<"::4.Quit Program::"<<'\n'
        <<"Your Option: ";
    cin>>Option;

    if (Option=="1")
    {
        cout<<"Welcome to Richardson Travel! Please enter your name: "<<endl;
        cin>>name;
        cout<<"Welcome, "<<name<<endl<< "Please enter your password: ";
        password_protection(password, password_input);
        cout<<"Dear, "<<name<<", if you would like to use Richardson Travel for your holidays, please enter: 'plan'."<<endl;
        cin>>input_to_start_program;
        while (input_to_start_program=="plan")
        {
            cout<<"Please enter the name of the file you want to read information from: "<<endl;
            cin>>name_of_file;
            file.open(name_of_file);
                if (file.is_open())
            {
                    while(file>>temp.name>>temp.x>>temp.y)
                {
                        file_info.push_back(temp);
                }

                for (int i=0; i<file_info.size(); i++)
                    cout<<i+1<<'\t'<<file_info[i].name<<endl;

                cout<<"In Richardson Travel we want you to be happy, and this is why we let you to add a city that is not on our list!"<<endl;
                cout<<"If you would like to use that option, please enter Y. If you are happy with the destinations we have on offer, please press N."<<endl;
                add_city(add, temp, file_info);

                cout<<"Please enter where you would like to go by entering integer values corresponding to the city names in order of when you would like to visit"<<endl<<"Enter 0 when you would like to stop planning your journey"<<endl;

                while(cin>>user_input && user_input!=0 && static_cast<size_t>(user_input) < file_info.size())
                {
                    choices.push_back(file_info[user_input-1]);
                    //cout<<"vector size = "<<choices.size()<<endl; <- tests whether the vector is being pushed back
                }

                for (int i=0; i<choices.size(); i++)
                    cout<<choices[i].name<<endl;

                cout<<"Thank you."<<endl<<"Here is a table of distances between the cities you have chosen: "<<endl;
                Table(choices, dist=0, distances2);
                    cout<<"Your possible route is: "<<endl;
                for(int i=0; i<choices.size(); i++)
                {
                    cout<<choices[i].name<<"  "<<"->"<<distances2[i]; // needs to display different dist
                }
                Distances_between_cities( distances2, maximum_distance=0, minimum_distance=0, sum_of_distances=0);

                cout<<"If you would like to plan another holiday with us, please enter 'plan', if you would like to access the menu, please enter anything else"<<endl;
                clear_vectors(file_info, choices);
                cin>>input_to_start_program;    
                system("cls");

            }
            else
                cout<<"Error. File not open"<<endl;
        }

    }
    else if(Option=="2")
    {
        system("CLS");
        read_from_file(name_of_file, temp, file_info);
        clear_vectors(file_info, choices);
        cout<<"Thank you, after pressing any key you will be redirected to the main menu"<<endl;
        system("pause");
        system("CLS");
    }
    else if (Option=="3")
    {
        system("CLS");
        cout<<"::INSTRUCTIONS::"<<'\n'
            <<"Wecome to Richardson Travel."<<'\n'<<"In order to use our program you have to have a file with the information about destinations stored. The file has to be attached to Resource Files folder in Visual Studio 2012. The file also has to be in the same folder as the source file. When prompted to enter the file name, the name of the file has to be entered accurately (case sensitive) and has to end with the type of file (eg. txt)"<<endl;
        cout<<"Thank you, after pressing any key you will be redirected to the main menu"<<endl;
        system ("PAUSE");
        system ("CLS");
    }
    else if(Option=="4")
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (Option>"4" || Option<"1")
    {
        system("CLS");
        cout<<"Invalid input"<<endl;
        system("PAUSE");
        system("CLS");
    }
    else
    {
        system ("CLS");
        cout<<"Invalid input"<<endl;
        system("Pause");
        system ("CLS");
    }

}
system ("pause");
}
```

In the edit i have added separate functions for quite a lot of things, which brings me to another question. How can I modify the read_from_file function so i can easily use in the the main function (right now i am only using it if the user selects option 2 fromt the menu, as i can't seem to figure out how to modify it not to use while loop), as theprogram is based on the while the file.is_open loop?

Comment: Too long to read, keep simplifying the code until you find the line that's culprit, or use a debugger. Only then post your code

Comment: @Kam, i did use a debugger , but it doesn't tell me where exactly the problem is. I can imagine that the error is happening somewhere here     <while (cin >> user_input && user_input != 0 && static_cast<size_t>(user_input) < file_info.size())
            {
                choices.push_back(file_info[user_input - 1]);
                //cout<<"vector size = "<<choices.size()<<endl; <- tests whether the vector is being pushed back
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < choices.size(); j++)
                cout << choices[j].name << endl;>

Comment: As a general note on code readability and good design practices, your main function should be factored into several smaller functions. For example, you could create separate functions for reading city coordinates, determining user choices and printing out the table.

Comment: It looks to me that you actually aren't allowing to pick the very LAST city.  Your condition `static_cast<size_t>(user_input) < file_info.size()` is wrong, because it doesn't account for one-based numbering.

Comment: You should have noticed that instead of entering `1`, `2`, `3`, `10`, `0` (to end), the input ended after `10`.

Comment: @BenVoigt, that would make sense, could you possibly give an example of how to solve this problem, as I don't think i have any idea :/
Yes, i have noticed that when testing the program, though should have seen it sooner

Comment: @AnastasiaRichardson: Well, you need that `index < file_info.size()`... but `index` in the next line is not `user_input`, it's `user_input-1`.

Comment: @BenVoigt, thank you! I have changed the index to user input-1 and it did the trick :)